# Why this CSS not valid?

Tags: css, dhtml

**I have this CSS:**

```
.optionQuiz a:hover{
        .Qtick{
            background-color: green;
        }
    }
```

**My HTML:**

```
<div class="optionQuiz">
<a href="#">
<span class="Qtick">1</span>
</a>
</div>
```

**My GOAL:**
My Goal is when the user hovers the mouse over the `<a>` the span with class within the `'<a>'` to be highlighted.

**MY Question:**
Why this CSS didn't work? This is indeed good way but seems such thing have not been invented? Why? Should I use JavaScript? I don't want. I want it in CSS way.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Because this isn't css, this is more of a less approach. Why can't you just do something like `.optionQuiz a:hover .Qtick {background-color: green;}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use JavaScript. You can solve it with CSS only on a very simple way. See the following snippet:

```css
.optionQuiz a:hover .Qtick {
  background-color: green;
}
.optionQuiz a:hover .other1 {
  background-color: blue;
}
.optionQuiz a:hover .other2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="optionQuiz">
  <a href="#">
    <span class="Qtick">1</span>
    <span class="other1">2</span>
    <span class="other2">3</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

With plain CSS you can't use nested selectors.

You can do it using a pre-processor like Sass, PostCSS, Less...

If you want to use just CSS you have to use something like this:

```css
a:hover span.Qtick{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="optionQuiz">
<a href="#">
<span class="Qtick">1</span>
</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what

```
  .Qtick{
            background-color: green;
        }
```

is for...

if you want to change the  color
this will do:

```
.optionQuiz a:hover{
            background-color: green;

    }
```

if you want only the span to be highlighter use the following selector:

```
.optionQuiz a:hover >span.Qtick{
        background-color: green;

}
```